# Add another SSL connection

Tags: java, ssl

We have a Windows server running a Java Servlet on Tomcat with SSL set up already cosisting of a trusted root that provides a public key to a current connection and an imported public SSL key provided for connection to another server.

We now need to set up a new SSL connection to another new server.  Do we use the current keystore and set up another trusted root within it for this new additional connection?  Or do we have to set up a second keystore for the new trusted root for the new connection?

Thanks in advance

Regards

AJFarroll

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are talking about utilizing client certificate authentication.

You should not necessarily have to have multiple keystores.

The caveat on that statement is that if the CA that issued the client certificates is the same  issuer that issued the server certificates, the client resolution mechanism will have difficulty determining which client certificate to use.

You will most likely need to have an extension of javax.net.ssl.X509ExtendedKeyManager to allow you the ability to select the appropriate certificate alias.

You would need to override the method String chooseClientAlias(String[] keyType, Principal[] issuers, Socket socket).  The socket passed will most likely be an implementation of javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket. From the SSLSocket you could then get the javax.net.ssl.SSLSession using javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket.getSession(). From that you could glean the peer you are connected to and determine the appropriate certificate in your implementation.

Comment: Thanks Dave G.  I will have a quick investigation to determine if the CA issue for both Server certificates is the same and then get back to you.  I am not that experienced yet with SSL.

Comment: Let me know what you find ... I'll add example code later this morning with sample conversation information

Comment: Any luck with this? I did not have a chance to write up example code.

Comment: Hi, I have finally managed to get some feedback from our infrastructure guys (seperate location). I actually think the SSL is already set up and therefore hopefully no requirement for multiple SSL certificates via the one keystore. The SSL infrastructure set up is a purchased CA certificate and so the public key should already be available for the external connection.  Thanks for all your thoughts Dave G.  Once the actual encrypted connection has been accomplished I will confirm this question as answered.  Thanks again

Comment: One other tidbit for you - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html you can turn on debugging to see the packet exchange on the ssl conversation - it may be of benefit to see that as well to understand the handshake and negotiation.